# OpenCV does not free camera

Tags: c++, opencv, camera

I'm trying to release the camera in OpenCV and reinitialize it another time, but the problem is, I cannot properly release the camera. Asking OpenCV, the cv::VideoCapture, whether the camer is open or not, it says closed, but the little LED is still glowing and I cannot create another VideoCapture object around the same camera.

This is the include I use:

```
  #include <opencv2/opencv.hpp>
```

This is a little sample of code showing the problem:

```
cv::VideoCapture cap(0);

for(int i = 0; i < 20; i++) {
    cv::Mat frame;
    cap >> frame;

    cv::imshow("Test", frame);
    if (cv::waitKey(30) >= 0) { break; }
}

cap.release();
std::cout << "Camera is closed is : " << !cap.isOpened() << std::endl;

while(true) {
    if (cv::waitKey(30) >= 0) { break; }
}
```

As already mentioned, the output says the camera is closed, but the LED is glowing. When I try to create a new VideoCapture around the camera it fails and says the camera is busy.

Any ideas?

Comment: 2.4.8, sorry forgot to mention that

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**This might be a bug of OpenCV 2.4.8 with some devices**, you should check their bug tracker and post this issue there.

A fix for this problem might could be accomplished by putting the variable `cap` inside another scope:

```
{
    cv::VideoCapture cap(0);

    for(int i = 0; i < 20; i++) {
        cv::Mat frame;
        cap >> frame;

        cv::imshow("Test", frame);
        if (cv::waitKey(30) >= 0) 
            break;
    }
} 

/* At this point, cap was destroyed and your camera should be operational again */     

{
    cv::VideoCapture cap(0);

    for(int i = 0; i < 20; i++) {
        cv::Mat frame;
        cap >> frame;

        cv::imshow("AnotherTest", frame);
        if (cv::waitKey(30) >= 0) 
            break;
    }
}
```

> The documentation says that the camera will be deinitialized automatically in VideoCapture destructor.

The code should be enough to fix the problem. But as you noticed, the problem remains, so could be 1 of 2 things:

- This is really an issue inside OpenCV;
- There's a bug in driver of the camera, so updating it might solve the problem.

Comment: Just tested your code and it fails, it says:

HIGHGUI ERROR: V4L/V4L2: VIDIOC_CROPCAP
HIGHGUI ERROR: V4L/V4L2: VIDIOC_CROPCAP
VIDIOC_REQBUFS: Device or resource busy
VIDIOC_QBUF: Bad file descriptor

The first two errors are not important, they appeared at any version of OpenCV till now.

Comment: Ok, call `cap.release()` before the scope ends. Anyway, the documentation says that [*the camera will be deinitialized automatically in VideoCapture destructor*](http://docs.opencv.org/modules/highgui/doc/reading_and_writing_images_and_video.html?highlight=videocapture#videocapture), so my code should be enough to fix the problem. But as you noticed, the problem remains, so most probably this is an issue on OpenCV.

Comment: Doesn't work either.

Strange thing is, when I ask cap whether it is closed or not after calling release(), it says it is closed ...

Comment: Just checked that, I think I'll follow your advice and wait for an update of OpenCV. Thanks for your help.